# How can I create a new column in a data frame that contains a new assigned ID number, 1 through 33, for the long ID numbers assigned in the dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr, assign, geom-bar

I'd like to keep the column of original Id numbers, but I'd like to create a new Id number for each participant in my dataset, so when I create a `geom_bar` graph it's not using decimals and looking strange.

This is the current R code I have written.

```
library(dplyr)
unique_ids <- daily_activity %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarize(days_used = n_distinct(ActivityDate)).
```

This is the current data frame:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T96hM.png

As you can see, it has the Id number, and when I `geom_bar` this, it becomes these skinny bars due to the program creating numbers using scientific notation, ie = 7e+09.

I'd like to create a new column in this data frame that assigns a new number Id to each of the long Id numbers. That way, I have a unique identifier for each super long Id. I'm curious if there is a way to auto assign numbers starting at 1 and going up to whatever the last number needs to be, positive integers only. I'll then use a note on my graph that says, "See table for Id pairings" or something...

Does any of this make sense? I'm very new to R, coding, graphing, analysis...Any suggestions of ideas I can try? Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(daily_activity)`?

Comment: How do I use dput(daily_activity)?? In this comment? Also, I don't know why my image didn't show up.

Comment: Your image didn't show because you display it as code. Use `dput(daily_activity)` in your console and copy paste that in your question.

Comment: When I input that dput(daily_activity) into my console it comes back with thousands of lines of data, and it's jumbled and crazy looking. It doesn't give much reference to anything I'm attempting to do, as I have about 20 data frames I've downloaded.

Comment: I appreciate your attempted assistance, it seems I'm too new to all this that I find it difficult to even post a question properly. I've now tried 6 different ways to post my image and nothing is working. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to post an image if it refuses to show up...??

Comment: You could use `head(dput(daily_activity), 20)` which returns the first 20 rows of your data.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a separate look up table for converting old IDs to new IDs. Something like this:

```r
lookup_table = input_table %>%
  select(old_IDs = IDs) %>%
  distinct()

lookup_table$new_IDs = 1:nrow(lookup_table)
```

You can then join the look up table to the original table:

```r
output_table = input_table %>%
  innner_join(lookup_table, by = c("IDs" = "old_IDs")) %>%
```

Comment: `unique_ids <- daily_activity %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarize(days_used = n_distinct(ActivityDate))`                                                                                                                             
     unique_ids$new_identifier <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
                               15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 ,24 ,25, 
                               26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33)

Comment: This is what I did instead, two different codes there, if you can see the separation. It gave me the added identifier column, but I had to input the identifiers manually. I was hoping there was a way to do this where they would auto fill in the numbers up to as high as I needed it to go...but I couldn't figure that out, so this is what I did. Probably not the prettiest of codes but...